# Sql query get from each category

Tags: mysql, sql

In mySql I have 3 table name `emp`, `emp_cat` and `emp_cat_relation`. `Employee Id` from `emp` table and `employee category id` from `emp_cat` relate in `emp_cat_relation` table.

How I can pick last joined employee (1 or 2 row as I want) name and join date from each category using single sql query.

Date field in emp table

Comment: Put up sample data from each table and put up an expected output

Comment: Do you have a date field the `emp_cat_relation` table?

Comment: Please show us your tables structure.

Comment: no date field in emp table

Comment: @RzRasel what table is join date from?

Comment: Dear @Matt Date field in emp table

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LIMIT` & `ORDER BY` Functions

```
SELECT *
FROM emp e
INNER JOIN emp_cat_relation ecr ON e.employee_id = ecr.employee_id
INNER JOIN emp_cat ec ON ecr.employee_category_id = ec..employee_category_id
ORDER BY e.date
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: It's not work, the result return only limit 2, not each category employee.